# In dplyr, how to delete and rename columns that don't exist, manipulate all names, and name a new variable using a string?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How can I simplify or perform the following operations using `dplyr`:

1. Run a function on all `data.frame` names, like `mutate_each(funs())` for values, e.g.

   ```
   names(iris) <- make.names(names(iris))
   ```
2. Delete columns that do NOT exist (i.e. delete nothing), e.g.

   ```
   iris %>% select(-matches("Width")) # ok
   iris %>% select(-matches("X"))     # returns empty data.frame, why?
   ```
3. Add a new column by name (string), e.g.

   ```
   iris %>% mutate_("newcol" = 0) # ok

   x <- "newcol"
   iris %>% mutate_(x = 0) # adds a column with name "x" instead of "newcol"
   ```
4. Rename a data.frame colname that does not exist

   ```
   names(iris)[names(iris)=="X"] <- "Y"

   iris %>% rename(sl=Sepal.Length) # ok
   iris %>% rename(Y=X)             # error, instead of no change
   ```

Comment: For number 3 why not? `iris %>% mutate_( 'x' = 0)`

Comment: @BondedDust, that adds a column named "x" while they want it named "newcol" or whatever name is stored n x.

Comment: `x <- "Sepal.Length"; iris %>% rename_(.dots = setNames(x,"sl"))` works but that can not be used for (4) because a missing colnames throws an error

Comment: It looks like iris %>% select(-matches("X")) now returns the full iris data.frame.  The everything argument in the answer below isn't necessary anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. I would use setNames for this:

```
iris %>% setNames(make.names(names(.)))
```

2. Include everything() as an argument for select:

```
iris %>% select(-matches("Width"), everything())
iris %>% select(-matches("X"), everything())
```

3. To my understanding there's no other shortcut than explicitly naming the string like you already do:

```
iris %>% mutate_("newcol" = 0)
```

Comment: thank you very much! Perhaps someone see a way for 3, but I marked it es solved!

Comment: dplyr 0.5.0 seems to work slightly differently; the everything() argument will add column "Width" back in. The syntax with 0.5.0 should be:

`iris %>% select(-matches("Width"))`

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following solution for #4:

```
iris %>% 
  rename_at(vars(everything()), 
            function(nm)
              recode(nm, 
                     Sepal.Length="sl",
                     Sepal.Width = "sw",
                     X = "Y")) %>%
  head()
```

The last line just for convenient output of course.

Answer (score 1):

1 through 3 are answered above. I came here because I had the same problem as number 4. Here is my solution:

```
df <- iris
```

Set a name key with the columns to be renamed and the new values:

```
name_key <- c(
  sl = "Sepal.Length",
  sw = "Sepal.Width",
  Y = "X"
)
```

Set values not in data frame to NA. This works for my purpose better. You could probably just remove it from `name_key`.

```
for (var in names(name_key)) {
  if (!(name_key[[var]] %in% names(df))) {
    name_key[var] <- NA
  }
}
```

Get a vector of column names in the data frame.

```
cols <- names(name_key[!is.na(name_key)])
```

Rename columns

```
for (nm in names(name_key)) {
  names(df)[names(df) == name_key[[nm]]] <- nm
}
```

Select columns

```
df2 <- df %>%
  select(cols)
```

I'm almost positive this can be done more elegantly, but this is what I have so far. Hope this helps, if you haven't solved it already!

Comment: `name_key <- name_key[name_key %in% names(df)]` removes entries in `name_key` that are no columns in `df`. Then you can use `!!` together with `select()` or `rename()` as follows: `dplyr::select(df, !!name_key)`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the question n.2:

You can use the function `any_of` if you want to give explicitly the full names of the columns.

```
iris %>% 
    select(-any_of(c("X", "Sepal.Width","Petal.Width")))
```

This will not remove the non-existing column X and will remove the other two listed.

Otherwise, you are good with the solution with `matches` or a combination of `any_of` and `matches`.

```
  iris %>% 
    select(-any_of("X")) %>% 
    select(-matches("Width"))
```

This will remove explicitly X and the matches. Multiple matches are also possible.

```
iris %>% 
    select(-any_of("X")) %>%
    select(-matches(c("Width", "Spec"))) # use c for multiple matches
```